# Best way to utilize retrieved object's properties to populate arrays and subsequent labels?

Tags: arrays, swift, fetch

I have a database (parse-server) from which I can fetch objects which contain information. Some of the information in the properties of the objects are used to populate labels on table views. The way I have been populating, let's say, the userName and userLike labels are as follows:

**Appending Different Arrays with the objects properties**

```
var userName = [String]()
var userLikes = [String]()

func query(){
    let commentsQuery = PFQuery(className: "UserStuff")
    commentsQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (objectss, error) in
        if let objects = objectss{
            for object in objects{
                self.userName.append(object["userName"] as! String)
                self.userLikes.append(object["userLikes"] as! String)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ignore the fact that I don't have a `.whereKey` or any `else` statements to handle other cases... this is bare bones just for illustration of the question. Anyway, in this method, the `userName` and `userLikes` arrays are iterated through to populate the labels. The `for object in objectss{}` ensures that the indexes in one array (whether index 0,1,2,3,etc...) refers to/comes from the same object as the value in the index of the other array. However, I was wondering if would be better to do it as follows:

**Appending the whole object to a PFObject array**

```
var userObjects = [PFObject]()

func query(){
    let commentsQuery = PFQuery(className: "UserStuff")
    commentsQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (objectss, error) in
        if let objects = objectss{
            for object in objects{
                self.userName.append(object)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this method I could instead populate the labels with something like:

```
userNameLabel.text = String((userObjects[0])["userName"])
```

In this method all properties of the object would be accessible form the same array. I can see that this may have some advantages, but is this *definitively* the better way to do it/should I switch immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to say that the answer is that the latter of the two is probably the better method. This is because in the former, the information from a particular object is only linked between arrays by the order in the array. Any accidental or incorrectly scripted functions involving `.append` or `.remove` could skew the order between arrays and then an object's name might be the 3rd index in the `nameArray` but its likes may end up being the 4th index in the `likesArray` and it would be difficult to amend this issue. With the latter method, all information regarding an object's properties are linked to the object itself in the array and this issue is avoided.